# AWS Elastic Transcoder Preset for Alexa Skills

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-elastic-transcoder, video-conversion

I'm building an Alexa skill associated with a small serverless lambda function that converts video file in audio using AWS Elastic Transcoder service. However Alexa is really specific on the format that it wants: **MP3 with bit rate 48 kbps, and sample rate 16000 Hz.**

Is there any AWS Elastic Transcoder Preset predefined for this? I try to define my own with
Bitrate 48
SampleRate auto (because apparently 16000Hz is not an option) but without any success.

Any help on this would be highly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you thought of using FFmpeg as the converter and doing the conversion in the lambda function

Comment: you would run something similar to this: ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 16000 testausio.mp3

Comment: @ChuckLaPress yes, but I'm having some issue running the lambda function with ffmpeg for node , that is why if there was an option with elastic transcoder I would have liked it better. Plus it seems really weird that an AWS service (Elastic Transcoder) doesn't support presets useful for another of their service (Alexa).

Comment: Your right,  I'm not trying to be funny but looking at your question and reading through a couple answers lots here: https://www.google.com/search?q=running+ffmpeg+in+lambda&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS691US691&oq=running+ffmpeg+in+lambda&aqs=chrome..69i57.25502j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8. I see that aws marketplace has a ffmpeg solution also, though none are cheap. You may have to resort to running a Linux machine and convert it per job.

Comment: look specifically at the first two google hits andd then HVM on aws marketplace. unless this app is for a business solution, I'd think seriously about converting the files locally and storing the converted mp3's to s3 for Alexa to playback. or put in a support ticket to the transcoder team with your use case and maybe they can provide an easier solution. Sorry that's the best I can help out with.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Those links are really familiar to me. Already had a look but I can't make it work and I think I need a linux environmnent. So I'm trying to create a EC2 instance and see if I can run things there and finally make it work...but it's not very strightforward. Thanks  again!!!

Comment: Your welcomed, give this a view https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide and this forum q&a  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=332091 lately good luck

Answer (score 0):

Following preset settings worked for me:

[image]